# How to migration between each environment of SPO modern site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, modern-team-site

I would like to ask an experienced person.
How did you move your SharePoint Online Modern Team Site list, library settings and SPFX programs from development to test and from test to production?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the lists and libraries between environment, I would suggest you use the mover tool. Please read this article for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mover-o365-to-o365

For SPFX solutions, you could download them from the test environment. Then deploy them on your product environemnt.

https://sharepoint-tricks.com/backup-your-sharepoint-spfx-solutions/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have a question. Your suggestion mover tool is free?

Comment: Yes, it is free.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think "Save as template" is easy to use. But you think mover is more recommend?

Comment: The default limit when saving a list template with data is 50 MB. So if your lists/libraries have more than 50MB data, you cannot save it as template.

Comment: Thank you! I understood. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 3rd party tools to migrate / move content between the SharePoint tenants. Their is no OOTB way,  you can try different tools as they offer free trail

- [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/sharepoint-migration?msclkid=42d044b2e6a7137dd6301a7c4db309e3&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=srps_bng_sgd_mig_sp_us_trial&utm_term=%2Bmove%20%2Bsharepoint&utm_content=sharepoint_move)

Another way is using the Save as template method.

- Save the source site as a template
- Then attach the saved template to the destination site in SharePoint
  Online
- Copy the content from source site to the destination site in
  SharePoint Online

[Read more here](https://expert-advice.org/office365/migrate-sharepoint-online-different-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-tenants/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have money so your second suggestion as Save as template is better I think.